# Number equal rows in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Logical = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),
  A = c(1,2,3,2,3,1),
  B = c(1,0.05,0.80,0.05,0.80,1),
  C = c(1,10.80,15,10.80,15,1))
```

Which looks like:

```
  Logical A    B    C
1    TRUE 1 1.00  1.0
2   FALSE 2 0.05 10.8
3   FALSE 3 0.80 15.0
4   FALSE 2 0.05 10.8
5   FALSE 3 0.80 15.0
6   FALSE 1 1.00  1.0
```

I want to add a new variable, `D`, which is an integer based on the following rules: either a `0` if `df$Logical` is `TRUE`, or an integer that is the same for all rows of variables `A`, `B` and `C` that are approximately (because they are doubles, so within a floating point margin of error) equal, starting at `1`.

The expected output here:

```
  Logical A    B    C D
1    TRUE 1 1.00  1.0 0
2   FALSE 2 0.05 10.8 1
3   FALSE 3 0.80 15.0 2
4   FALSE 2 0.05 10.8 1
5   FALSE 3 0.80 15.0 2
6   FALSE 1 1.00  1.0 3
```

First row gets `0` because `Logical` is `TRUE`, second and fourth row get `1` because the variables `A`, `B` and `C` are approximately equal there, same for second and fifth row. Row six gets a `3` because it is the next unique row. Note that the order of integers assigned in `D` is irrelevant except for the `0`. e.g., rows 2 and 4 could also be assigned `2` as long as this integer is unique in the other cases of `D`.

---

I have considered using aggregating functions. For example using `ddply`:

```
library("plyr")
df$foo <- 1:nrow(df)
foo <- dlply(df,.(A,B,C),'[[',"foo")
df$D <- 0
for (i in 1:length(foo)) df$D[foo[[i]]] <- i
df$D[df$Logical] <- 0
```

works, but I am not sure how well this will do with floating point errors (I guess I could round the values here before this call and it should be quite stable though). With a loop it is quite easy:

```
df$D <- 0
c <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  if (!isTRUE(df$Logical[i]) & df$D[i]==0)
  {
    par <- sapply(1:nrow(df),function(j)!df$Logical[j]&isTRUE(all.equal(unlist(df[j,c("A" ,"B", "C")]),unlist(df[i,c("A" ,"B", "C")]))))
    df$D[par] <- c
    c <- c+1
  }
}
```

but this is very slow for larger data frames.

Comment: Could you convert columns `A`, `B` and `C` to factors? With the sample dataset, that looks like it would be OK (wrt tolerance issues of floating point numbers)

Answer (score 4):

As per Matthew Dowle's comments below, `data.table` can group numeric values, distinguishing between them with `.Machine$double.eps^.5` tolerance. With that in mind, a `data.table` solution should work:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(df)

DT[, D := 0]

.GRP <- 0

DT[!Logical, D := .GRP <- .GRP + 1, by = "A,B,C"]

#    Logical A    B    C foo D
# 1:    TRUE 1 1.00  1.0   1 0
# 2:   FALSE 2 0.05 10.8   2 1
# 3:   FALSE 3 0.80 15.0   3 2
# 4:   FALSE 2 0.05 10.8   4 1
# 5:   FALSE 3 0.80 15.0   5 2
# 6:   FALSE 1 1.00  1.0   6 3
```

As Matthew Dowle writes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019561), `.GRP` is implemented in data.table 1.8.3, but I'm still with 1.8.2

---

Follow up from comments, here's the NEWS item from 1.8.2. Will add to `?data.table`, thanks for highlighting!

> Numeric columns (type `double`) are now allowed in keys and ad hoc by.
>     `J()` and `SJ()` no longer coerce `double` to `integer`. `i` join columns
>     which mismatch on numeric type are coerced silently to match
>     the type of `x`'s join column. **Two floating point values
>     are considered equal (by grouping and binary search joins) if their
>     difference is within sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)**, by default. See example
>     in `?unique.data.table`. Completes FRs #951, #1609 and #1075. This paves the
>     way for other atomic types which use `double` (such as `POSIXct` and `bit64`).
>     Thanks to Chris Neff for beta testing and finding problems with keys
>     of two numeric columns (bug #2004), fixed and tests added.

Comment: Yes that should work. I don't quite understand the first sentence about `factor` though. `data.table` internally has code to group `double` columns within machine tolerance, keeping `double` as `double`. It doesn't convert to `character` or `factor` and rely on formatting precision, like base does. See `example(unique.data.table)` for a `tan(pi(...))` example. The documentation could be clearer up in `?data.table` that grouping `double` columns is within machine tolerance. It uses the same tolerance as `all.equal` i.e. `.Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, thanks for the clarification. The `factor` stuff was a bit of a remnant from an earlier version of the answer. I'll clear it up after looking at `example(unique.data.table)`.

Comment: Ok cool. I was surprised there's nothing about grouping tolerance for `double` in `?data.table`, so will put something in ...

Comment: @MatthewDowle, Thanks again. With the (great!) ability to use `double` columns as key columns, I'd find it very helpful to have info under `?data.table` mentioning the tolerance (or maybe it's there and I missed it...)

Comment: Oh, it was in NEWS only from 1.8.2. I'll add that item as edit, and will add to `?data.table`...