# Assigning unique id to duplicated rows

Tags: r, duplicates, dataframe

If i have a data frame which looks like this:

```
x y
13 a
14 b
15 c
15 c
14 b
```

and I wanted each group of equal rows to have a unique id, like this:

```
x y id
13 a 1
14 b 2
15 c 3
15 c 3
14 b 2
```

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Is your example overly simplistic or does it contain typo, as here id is exactly the same as x?

Comment: maybe my example is a little misleading, i'll change it!

Comment: A similar question using `data.table`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018696/data-table-key-indices-or-group-counter

Comment: @by0 check my improved solution which uses `interaction` function instead of `paste0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first thing I thought:

Make a new variable which just combines the two columns by pasting their values to strings:

```
a<-paste0(z$x,z$y) #z is your data.frame
```

The make this as a factor and combine it to your dataframe:

```
cbind(z,id=factor(a,labels=1:length(unique(a))))
```

EDIT: @flodel was concerned about using `paste0`, it's better to use ordinary `paste`, or interaction:

```
a<-interaction(z,drop=TRUE)
cbind(z,id=factor(a,labels=1:length(unique(a))))
```

This is assuming that you want to separate `x=ab`, `y=c`, and `x=a`,`y=bc`. If not, then use `paste0`.

Comment: (+1) I'd change `a` to `do.call(paste0, z)`. And `1:length(unique(a))` to `seq_along(unique(a))`

Comment: Good points, I never remember the `seq_along` and `do.call` was new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have a bit of a concern with the `paste0` approach. If your columns contained more complex data, you could end up with surprising results, e.g. imagine:

```
 x  y
ab  c
 a bc
```

One solution is to replace `paste0(...)` with `paste(..., sep = "@")`. Even so, you cannot come up with a `sep` general enough that it will work with any type of data as there is always a non-zero probability that `sep` will be contained in some kind of data.

A more robust approach is to use a split/transform/combine approach. You can certainly do it with the `base` package but `plyr` makes it a bit easier:

```
library(plyr)
.idx <- 0L
ddply(df, colnames(df), transform, id = (.idx <<- .idx + 1L))
```

If this is too slow, I would recommend a `data.table` approach, as proposed here: [data.table "key indices" or "group counter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018696/data-table-key-indices-or-group-counter)

Comment: Good point about `paste0`, I added a better solution which is actually more neater than the original answer.

Comment: @Hemmo. I think using `interaction` is equivalent to using `paste(..., sep = '.')`; theoretically, it suffers the same (unlikely) problem I was discussing.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right that they actually produce the same thing, but they actually both work correctly in situation you discussed, as you get `ab.c` and `a.bc` which are distinct. And I guess that is what is wanted. `paste0` doesn't work properly though (that works if separation is not wanted).