# adding a record counter to a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, auto-increment

I have an existing data.table that I am wanting to add an 'identity' column to.

I know how to add a column e.g:

```
DT$newCol <- x
```

However I am struggling to make the new value an auto-incrementing counter from 1 to n.

I would have asked as a comment to this question ([data.table "key indices" or "group counter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018696/data-table-key-indices-or-group-counter)) as it is related, however I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample data?

Comment: `DT[, newcol := .I]` maybe?

Comment: @thelatemail I think you mean `.N`.

Comment: On testing it is found that .I produces serial numbers while .N produces nrow in each row of new column. '.I' is the solution.

Comment: @rnso I meant `DT[, newcol := 1:.N]`.

Comment: Even if not asked, this can become handy in the future also: numbering rows by group
    `library(data.table)
    agroup <- c(rep("A", times = 2), rep("B", times = 7))
    dt <- data.table(agroup)
    dt[, anothercounter := seq_along(.I), by = "agroup"]
    dt`

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone for your help. As I all the answers have come in commments I can't select an answer to credit. But thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of completeness in case someone stumbles across this.

```
DT[, newcol := 1:.N]
```

is how I solved the problem. Thanks to go @thelatemail and @Simon