# .GRP in R data.table for large tables (crash)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large `data.table` with >300k rows and 884 columns (see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M1JXOpSORyUKCnzg0kCLzOvSlwquWNAC/view?usp=sharing) for data in CSV, 700MB).

I am trying to get labels for identical rows. This is what `.GRP` does wonderfully in `data.table`. Unfortunately, it takes forever to run, and in most cases crashes the Rsession. Any ideas on how to splitting up the problem or speeding up the solution would greatly be appreciated.

Here a MWE with the data mentioned above:

```
  troutmat <- fread("troutmat.csv")
  troutmat[,grp:=.GRP, names(troutmat)]
```

-> crashes Rsession (4.1.1. with data.table 1.14.2 on a 16 core Windows server)

Happy to open a bug report, if needed.

EDIT:
Essentially, it's the same question as: [data.table "key indices" or "group counter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018696/data-table-key-indices-or-group-counter) but with a much larger dataset. I am trying to find a fast way to find duplicated rows, but in a way that I know which row is a duplicate of which other row.

Comment: Please be careful with code you provide as a MWE: this won't run unless `troutman.csv` is oddly an object that contains the filename.

Comment: sorry, forgot the "" in the fread() command.

Comment: how many threads does `data.table` use ? can you check `getDTthreads()`

Comment: @SametSökel it uses all, so 16.

Comment: @PukiLuki ok, if you are grouping for every variable, isn't it the same as adding row number ?

Comment: Essentially, it's the same as the question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018696/data-table-key-indices-or-group-counter , BUT with a much larger data.set. I added the reference in the question. So if I understand correctly, it's not adding row numbers, right? Thanks.

Comment: A `data.table` key is intended to be used to sort the data internally (benefits binary search, faster joins, faster grouping, and other benefits). While setting *all columns* as keys is supported, does it make sense?

Comment: I understand, thanks for the explanations. However, in this case I am trying to find a fast way to find duplicated rows, but in a way that I know which row is a duplicate of which other row.

Comment: Grouping by all columns is the same as row number only if there are no duplicated rows.